# Удалить все теги, заменить

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строчка

```
<div id="texts">
<p id=ss>Текст</p>
<p>Текст.
Текст <span class=sv>fds</span>Текст.
Текст ТекстТекст Текст.<a data=link>link</a></p>
</div>
```

Как удалить все теги, но оставить их содержимое, а заместо тега

```
</p>
```

Вставить

```
/n
```

Comment: `</?p>` этим заменяйте это `/n`

Comment: А `</?\w+/?>` этим пустоту.

Comment: Ну там немного надо возится ещё чтобы аттрибуты удалял, но сложности не должно возникать.

Comment: Можно готовый пример, трудно мне регулярки еще составлять...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алгоритм:

1. Заменяем все `</p>` на `\n</p>`
2. Берём всё текстовое содержимое

```js
const texts = document.querySelector('#texts');

texts.innerHTML = texts.innerHTML.replaceAll('</p>', '\n</p>');

console.log('innerHTML:\n', texts.innerHTML);
console.log('textContent:\n', texts.textContent);
```

```html
<div id="texts">
<p id=ss>Текст</p>
<p>Текст.
Текст <span class=sv>fds</span>Текст.
Текст ТекстТекст Текст.<a data=link>link</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Кстати да тоже думал о таком решении, но так как проблема не полностью описана в вопросе на стал спорить с автором)

Comment: @eccs0103 Спорить с автором - это тут у всех любимое занятие :)

Answer (score 0):

Регулярное выражение `<!?/?\w+(\s[\w-]+(=['"]?.*?['"]?)?)*/?>` выберет все теги - будь то с аттрибутом или без. Осталось только поставить его в `replace()` и заменить На то что нужно.

---

Проверил у себя в VS Code:

[image]

Выделяется все кроме внутреннего текста.